# ValueError in Matrix Operation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to do matrix operations on matrices that may be undefined. (i.e. A is 2x2 and cannot be multiplied with B with the dimension 3x2.)

```
print '3.1) ',
try: a + c
except ValueError: print 'Not Defined'
```

This works, but I have multiple operations so I tried to create a function like so:

```
def matrix(math):
    try: math
    except ValueError: print "Not Defined"
    print math
```

where math is the operation such as AB or (A+B).

However, the code doesn't work on operations that are not defined. How can I fix it to where it works on both defined and undefined functions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you provide us a non-working (small) dataset example? Also note that `math` **is** defined, but can be empty (you should test it with `if math: ...` instead of `try: ... except...`).

Answer (score 0):

one solution:

```
def matrix(A, B, function):
    try:
        print function(A,B)
    except ValueError:
        print "Not Defined"
```

where function is for instance:

```
def function(A,B):
    return A+B
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the expression as a string and wait to evaluate it until you're in the function's try block:

```
def matrix(math_string):
    try: result = eval(math_string)
    except ValueError:
        print "Not Defined"
        return
    print result
```

Use would look like this:

```
matrix('a + b')
```